# Power BI - Need DAX or any function to calculate data

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

This is my table
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/704LS.png)

i need sum of all totalworkhours which is 780 in new column 'Nume' where date is 11-nov-23 and sum of all totalworkhours which is 200 in new column 'nume' where date is 12-nov-23 in each row. answer should look like below table.
[Output needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76bq7.png)

this is what i tried to calculate sumx(filter(MarginReport,MarginReport[WkSTDate]=MarginReport[WkSTDate]),MarginReport[TotalWorkHours])

but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem by creating Custom Column **nume** like this:

```
nume = CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[TotalWorkHours]), 
    ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[WkSTDate])
)
```

**ALLEXCEPT** removes all context filters in the table except filters that have been applied to the specified columns. So, whenever any column but WkSTDate from your table is used, the formula will remove any slicer filters, providing a value equal to the sum of TotalWorkHours. When the data is sliced on WkSTDate, a filter will be applied at the row level.